# Michael Hartl: Chapter 7 - app crashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I've just completed Chapter 7 of Hartl's RoR tutorial.
All the Spec tests pass, and the app runs as expected on localhost.
The app however crashed on Heroku.  The logs don't make any sense.
I explicitly set the Ruby version to 1.9.3 as suggested by Heroku warning messages, but that made no difference.
Running it on Heroku

Ruby -v gives me 1.9.3, the logs suggest 1.9.1

Not sure this is the correct way to post the logs, but the following is the dump of the Heroku log:

---

```
> 2013-06-30T16:52:30.721129+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
> 2013-06-30T16:52:30.829645+00:00 app[web.1]:  from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in
> `load_dependency' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.828830+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
> 2013-06-30T16:52:30.829645+00:00 app[web.1]:  from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in
> `require' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.829645+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in
> `block in require' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.829645+00:00 app[web.1]:
> /app/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': superclass mismatch
> for class User (TypeError) 2013-06-30T16:52:30.829645+00:00
> app[web.1]:   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in
> `require_or_load' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.829840+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in
> `require_dependency' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.829645+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in
> `require' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830407+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in
> `each' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.829645+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in
> `depend_on' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830407+00:00 app[web.1]:  from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in
> `each' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830407+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in
> `eager_load!' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830407+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in
> `block (2 levels) in eager_load!' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830565+00:00
> app[web.1]:   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in
> `block in <module:Finisher>' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830407+00:00
> app[web.1]:   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in
> `block in eager_load!' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830565+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in
> `block in run_initializers' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830565+00:00
> app[web.1]:   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in
> `run_initializers' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830565+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
> `run' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830565+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in
> `each' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830565+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
> `instance_exec' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830565+00:00 app[web.1]:  from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in
> `initialize!' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830700+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in
> `initialize' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830700+00:00 app[web.1]:     from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in
> `instance_eval' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830565+00:00 app[web.1]:  from
> /app/config.ru:3:in `require' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830700+00:00
> app[web.1]:   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in
> `eval' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830565+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
> /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
> 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830700+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config.ru:3:in
> `block in <main>' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830565+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in
> `method_missing' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830700+00:00 app[web.1]:     from
> /app/config.ru:in `new' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830838+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in
> `block in <top (required)>' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830838+00:00
> app[web.1]:   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in
> `start' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830700+00:00 app[web.1]:  from
> /app/config.ru:in `<main>' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830700+00:00
> app[web.1]:   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in
> `wrapped_app' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830700+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in
> `parse_file' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830700+00:00 app[web.1]:     from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in
> `app' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830700+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in
> `app' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830838+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in
> `start' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830838+00:00 app[web.1]:  from
> script/rails:6:in `require' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830838+00:00
> app[web.1]:   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in
> `tap' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830838+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in
> `<top (required)>' 2013-06-30T16:52:30.830838+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
> script/rails:6:in `<main>' 2013-06-30T16:52:32.248386+00:00
> heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
> 2013-06-30T16:52:32.258303+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
> starting to crashed 2013-06-30T16:54:22+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]:
> Slug compilation started 2013-06-30T16:55:15.220931+00:00 heroku[api]:
> Deploy b5a74ad by osman.uk.oa@gmail.com
> 2013-06-30T16:55:15.263331+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v12 created by
> osman.uk.oa@gmail.com 2013-06-30T16:55:15.300675+00:00 heroku[api]:
> Deploy b5a74ad by osman.uk.oa@gmail.com
> 2013-06-30T16:55:15.493971+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
> crashed to starting 2013-06-30T16:55:15+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]:
> Slug compilation finished 2013-06-30T16:55:17.697516+00:00
> heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server
> -p 48620` 2013-06-30T16:55:19.476876+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support
> for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and
> bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as
> lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release
> notes for more on this:
> http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released.
> (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
> 2013-06-30T16:55:19.476876+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You
> have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these
> plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in
> your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and
> config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on
> this:
> http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released.
> (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
> 2013-06-30T16:55:20.731749+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
> 2013-06-30T16:55:20.731749+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
> 2013-06-30T16:55:20.731749+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.13
> application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:48620
> 2013-06-30T16:55:20.731749+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown
> server 2013-06-30T16:55:20.731749+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to
> database specified by DATABASE_URL 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815078+00:00
> app[web.1]:   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in
> `require' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.814340+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
> 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815078+00:00 app[web.1]:  from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in
> `each' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815078+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in
> `depend_on' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815078+00:00 app[web.1]:  from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in
> `require' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815078+00:00 app[web.1]:
> /app/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': superclass mismatch
> for class User (TypeError) 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815078+00:00
> app[web.1]:   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in
> `block in require' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815078+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in
> `require_or_load' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815078+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in
> `require_dependency' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815078+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in
> `load_dependency' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815450+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
> /app/config.ru:3:in `require' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815283+00:00
> app[web.1]:   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
> `run' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815283+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in
> `block in run_initializers' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815283+00:00
> app[web.1]:   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in
> `each' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815078+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in
> `block (2 levels) in eager_load!' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815283+00:00
> app[web.1]:   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in
> `each' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815283+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in
> `eager_load!' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815283+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in
> `block in <module:Finisher>' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815283+00:00
> app[web.1]:   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in
> `block in eager_load!' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815283+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in
> `run_initializers' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815450+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in
> `method_missing' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815450+00:00 app[web.1]:     from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in
> `parse_file' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815878+00:00 app[web.1]:     from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in
> `app' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815450+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
> /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815283+00:00
> app[web.1]:   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
> `instance_exec' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815450+00:00 app[web.1]:  from
> /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
> 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815450+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config.ru:in
> `<main>' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815878+00:00 app[web.1]:     from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in
> `start' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815878+00:00 app[web.1]:  from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in
> `block in <top (required)>' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815878+00:00
> app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
> 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815878+00:00 app[web.1]:  from script/rails:6:in
> `<main>' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815878+00:00 app[web.1]:     from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in
> `start' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815283+00:00 app[web.1]:  from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in
> `initialize!' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815450+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in
> `instance_eval' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815878+00:00 app[web.1]:  from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in
> `app' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815878+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in
> `wrapped_app' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815450+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
> /app/config.ru:in `new' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815878+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in
> `tap' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815878+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in
> `<top (required)>' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815450+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in
> `initialize' 2013-06-30T16:55:20.815450+00:00 app[web.1]:     from
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in
> `eval' 2013-06-30T16:55:21.891432+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
> with status 1 2013-06-30T16:55:21.903767+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State
> changed from starting to crashed
```

---

Needless to say being a complete newbie the logs make little sense, but everything was working fine until chapter 7.  So it's got to be a schoolboy error on my part somewhere, but I don't know how to debug the error and the google searches don't give me anything "firm".

Any advice warmly appreciated.

Oz

---

The following provides a link to my repo and details of the User class:

https://github.com/OsmanAhmed/sample_app

The following is my User class.  I did have a look at this but couldn't see anything obviously wrong:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base


 attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = user.email.downcase } 

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
  after_validation { self.errors.messages.delete(:password_digest) }

end
```

---

Comment: Don't worry about the ruby 1.9.1 in the file paths - that's normal, the ABI didn't change between ruby 1.9.1 and 1.9.3

Comment: I am assuming you've been commiting to Github? Could you provide link to the repo? The logs suggest there is some problem in your user model.

Comment: Could you paste User class? Log says `superclass mismatch for class User (TypeError)`

Comment: I've added a Link to the Repo to the main question: https://github.com/OsmanAhmed/sample_app as well as details of the User class.  Weird thing is that it's running happily on my local machine, so the class technically is fine... right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your app/controllers/example_user.rb file, which also defines a `User` class.

In development mode this file probably never gets loaded - it's not where rails would expect to find a user class. In production however, rails loads all the files in the app up front (at least everything in the paths given by `eager_load_paths` and happens to load this one first.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm still not sure why it caused a problem this time around, but I have just commented out the entire app/controllers/example_user.rb file, committed and pushed it back to Heroku.  All is working as expected.  I'm gonna do some more reading around this.  Many thanks again!